# How to connect multiple Realtime Databases from the same project (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a new Realtime Database in the same project.

I followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances) but got some errors.

```
final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(); // default database instance

// using ref()
final db2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('https://mydb2.us-central1.firebasedatabase.app');
// error Invalid Firebase Database path
// Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

// using refFromURL()
final db3 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.refFromURL('https://mydb2.us-central1.firebasedatabase.app');
// error Invalid argument (must equal the current FirebaseDatabase instance databaseURL)
```

Same goes if using
`.firebaseio.com`  in the URL.

So what is the correct way to get DatabaseReference for secondary database in the same project?

Comment: Thanks for that. And good to see you found the cause of the problem.  --- cleaning up comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out by using `instanceFor()`:

```
final db2 = FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(
               app: Firebase.app(),
               databaseURL: 'https://mydb2.us-central1.firebasedatabase.app/'
            ).ref();
```